# Using regex to do matching in an URL

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, url

I am currently working on a project in which I need this to manipulate the parameters for esthetic purposes.

```
add_rewrite_rule( '([^/]*)/user/([^/]+)','index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&username=$matches[2]', 'top' );
-> would correctly retrieve the userID (in this case 232) from the following URL: http://mysite.com/userlisting/user/232

add_rewrite_rule( '([^/]*)/([^/]*)/user/([^/]+)','index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&username=$matches[2]', 'top' );
-> would correctly retrieve the userID (in this case 232) from the following URL: http://mysite.com/parent_directory/userlisting/user/232
```

Now I can add, let's say 10 of these rules, to makes sure I get at least 10 levels of hierarchy done, but what I would like to do is make it somewhat dynamic, based on how many levels the current "userlisting" has.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 add_rewrite_rule( '([^/]*)/([^/]*)/user/([^/]+)','index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&username=$matches[2]', 'top' );
 -> would correctly retrieve the userID (in this case 232) from the following URL: http://mysite.com/parent_directory/userlisting/user/232
```

**No**, it wouldn't.

- $matches[1] is `parent_directory`
- $matches[2] is `userlisting`
- $matches[3] would be `232` (ie the userID)

So your internal URL would be index.php?pagename=parent_directory&username=userlisting

---

As for actully, solving the problem, depends on how you want to handle the mulitple levels, iehow would they be passed to php, one possiblity would be

```
add_rewrite_rule( '(.+?)/user/([^/]+)','index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&username=$matches[2]', 'top' );
```

which in this case would give

index.php?pagename=parent_directory/userlisting&username=232

ie, as many directories, as are present in the url would make it into the "pagename" - you dont exclude in / from being part of the directory name.

But if you want the various hierarchy levels to be presented to PHP differnetly it could be done differnetly.